# Return the SUM of PastYrGrossPay column for employees who have 'Yes' in the ProjectManager column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

What I want to do is return the SUM of PastYrGrossPay column from the Employees table (from 01/1/2020 to 12/31/2020 (company didn't exist before 2020)). But I only want it to SUM up the PastYrGrossPay column for employees who have 'Yes' in the ProjectManager column on the Employees table. I also only want it to SUM up ProjectManager who have JobStatus 'Completed' (some Jobs say 'Incomplete' but I only want ProjectManager who have at least one 'Complete' job) in the Jobs table. Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROC spPastYrPay
    @SDate date = NULL,
    @EDate date = '12/31/2020',
    @PM varchar(3) = 'Yes',
    @Comp varchar(50) = 'Complete'
AS
BEGIN
    IF @SDate IS NULL
        SELECT @SDate = MIN(StartDate) FROM Employees

    DECLARE @TotPastYrPayroll money

    SELECT @TotPastYrPayroll = SUM(PastYrGrossPay)
    FROM Employees e
    JOIN Departments d ON e.EmpID = d.EmpID
    JOIN Jobs j ON d.DeptID = j.DeptID
    WHERE ((StartDate BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate) AND (ProjectManager LIKE @PM)
    AND (JobStatus LIKE @Comp))

    RETURN @TotPastYrPayroll
END

USE ABC_Mechanical
DECLARE @TotPastYrPayroll money
EXEC @TotPastYrPayroll = spPastYrPay
PRINT 'Project Managers (with at least one completed job) total payroll for the past year: $'
+ CONVERT(varchar, @TotPastYrPayroll, 1)
GO
```

Comment: Please provide sample data (DDL+DML) and expected results.

Comment: You need to use OUTPUT parameter to get the value out from the Stored procedure. And why are you adding all filter conditions as parameters. Since they are fixed, you don't need to. It is better if you can add table and data scripts when you post questions. @FirstOne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see here is that you don't need to pass all these parameters as they are predefined. You can pass them in where clause as filters as they are fixed in your question. If they are varie then you can pass them as parameters.

Nice thing about SPs is that you can have many output parameters. So in your case you can take the output parameter.

Even without an output parameter also you can do this by returning the variable.
Just as Select  @TotPastYrPayroll As [totalPayroll]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spPastYrPay (
 @SDate date = NULL,
@EDate date = '12/31/2020',
@PM varchar(3) = 'Yes',
@Comp varchar(50) = 'Complete',
@TotPastYrPayroll money  OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
 
 IF @SDate IS NULL
    SELECT @SDate = MIN(StartDate) FROM Employees

    
   SELECT @TotPastYrPayroll = SUM(PastYrGrossPay)
   FROM Employees e
   JOIN Departments d ON e.EmpID = d.EmpID
   JOIN Jobs j ON d.DeptID = j.DeptID
   WHERE ((StartDate BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate) AND (ProjectManager = @PM)
  AND (JobStatus LIKE @Comp))

END;
```

Executing the Stored procedure with output parameter

```
DECLARE @PastPayroll MONEY;

EXEC spPastYrPay
   @SDate = NULL,
   @EDate =  '12/31/2020',
   @PM = 'Yes',
   @Comp= 'Complete'
   @product_count = @PastPayroll OUTPUT;

SELECT @product_count AS 'Sum Of Payroll';
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually changed it around a little bit but it was with the help of what you had showed me!

Comment: @FirstOne I am happy to help you. if any help, feel free to reach me

Comment: If this answer is useful, please mark it as it will be a help for me @FirstOne